# SCRIPT5: Access is denied in IE9 for iframe on the same domain

Tags: ajax, gmail, internet-explorer-9, asyncfileupload

i am trying to submit form with file attached using iframe(through AJAX). I am using rails & remotipart gem. actually i've tried jquery.form.js library as well, but no luck. when i submit form i am getting "SCRIPT5: access denied" only in IE9 and when i am redirected to the page from my gmail account. It works fine when i go to my site and submit form with file attached, but doesn't work when i go to site through the link from gmail(for other emails it works). i checked how it works - it create hidden iframe set form.target= iframe.name(name of iframe) & iframe.src=javascript:false; When form is submitted it throw exception = "SCRIPT5: access denied". I've tried to set iframe.domain = domain of my site but didn't work - iframe = $("");
btw, i am submitting form to the same domain

Anyone solved this issue ?

Comment: Has anyone solved this one yet? I am facing this issue aswell..

Comment: I didn't :( if you'll have a solution please post it here.

Comment: I downgraded my jquery-rails version and it worked.

Comment: What jquery-rails version do you use now ?

Comment: I'm having same error but not actually from gmail. But it still happens even from my own site. Using remotipart and rails as well. Any progress from you @Dzmitry?

Comment: This issue has already been discussed here with solutions:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13483408/sending-files-file-upload-using-ajax-which-works-in-ie9

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about jQuery, but it is a common javascript error. IE doesn't allow forms with files attached to be submitted from a script.
If you however place the form in a seperate file and load it into an iframe, frame.form.submit() will work.

Comment: it allow forms with files to be submitted. It's only gmail & IE9 issue. I mean it doesn't work when you can to the form from gmail link. If you came from yahoo mail to the form - it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the lastest of JQuery(> jquery-1.8.0). Since the version 1.8.0, they solved somes IE9's bugs whose this error.

http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/30/jquery-1-8-1-released/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I was using the same versions as in the example. The example worked but I didn't manage to make it work in my app.

I'm using Backbone and I think it is related to creating the form dynamically, but unfortunately I didn't have time to debug the exact problem.

I moved to https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload, and now it works.