# Sending files /file upload using ajax which works in IE9

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, file-upload, multipartform-data

I need to upload files using ajax which has to be supported in IE9. I was using FormData as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5392344/sending-multipart-formdata-with-jquery-ajax). My code looks like this:

```
var files = new FormData();
JQuery.each($('#file')[0].files, function (i, file) {
    files.append('file', file);
});

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/url',
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: files,
    ...
});
```

This works fine in Safari and Firefox, but fails in IE9 as the FormData is not supported in IE9. I tried sending just as a file by setting:

```
data: $('#file')[0].files[0]
contentType: 'multipart/form-data'
```

This fails as the data is sent in url-encoded form and is cannot be parsed at the java side. Any help or pointer on how to solve this will be greatly appreciated. I need something that works across all browsers.

EDIT: I do not need any upload progress bar as the files are usually small. I do not need to upload multiple files. I just need a single file upload.

Comment: I found a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload

Comment: I cannot use specify the action in the form '<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">' as there can be multiple actions, depending on user input. So I have a 'click' action on the upload button, which determines the type of input we got from the user and redirect accordingly. We did have this earlier and it was working, but now the requirement changed to redirect to different url/function depending on user input.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot use Ajax (`XMLHttpRequest` in other words) for sending files, but you can implement a similar behavior using the `<iframe/>` with a `<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"/>` that contains an `<input type="file"/>` which sends a user chosen file using the "natural" way. You can use javascript to call the `form.submit()` then poll that `<iframe/>` from parent document to check whether the file upload process is done.

`jQuery` has [a lot of cool plugins](http://www.tutorialchip.com/jquery/9-powerful-jquery-file-upload-plugins/) for getting this job done, there is [my favorite one](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/), for example.

Comment: This answer looks useful too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery?lq=1

Comment: Thanks Danijar. That solved my problem. Looking forward to IE10

Comment: You can send a file to server using blob data.